# link and Id compare

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

When C=0 the line block, is there other way to compare Id than `Id.ToString().Contains(Id.Tostring())`

```
if (events_sL.Count != 0)
{
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < events_sL.Count; c++)
    {
        var a = (from s in db.Booked_s
                 where s.IdEvent.ToString().Contains(events_sL[c].EventId.ToString())
                 select s).ToList();
    }
}
```

Throws error as

> Linq to Entities doesn t recognized, the method
>   WebApplication.Models.Event get_Item(Int32)

Comment: is there any error getting?

Comment: the error say: Linq to Entities doesn t recognized, the method WebApplication.Models.Event get_Item(Int32).

Comment: one more thing, you have one events_sL[c].eventId at the time but many s.IdEvent=events_sL[c].eventId

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare? What is `s.IdEvent`? What is `events_sL[c].EventId`? Are you trying to see if one is a substring of the other?

Comment: many users can booked a event. So i try to get the booked in relation to one or many event. s.IdEvent = book.IdEvent

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. What is `s.IdEvent`? Why are you trying to compare it by converting it to a string? What is `event_sl[c]` and why are you trying to determine if it's a substring of the `s.IdEvent`? How is your data actually structured? Are you trying to join two tables?

Comment: ok, i just want to compare two tables of guid and get the object if the guid is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, you're trying to have `events_sL[c].EventId.ToString()` converted into SQL, but the LINQ provider doesn't know how to do that.  You want to just evaluate that value in memory, and then use the result in the query:

```
var foo = events_sL[c].EventId.ToString();//todo give better name
var a = (from s in db.Booked_s
         where s.IdEvent.ToString().Contains(foo)
         select s).ToList();
```